# No error with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have been messing around with php and sql quite many hours now. But It gives me no errors and it wont upload data from the form to the database. I Dont know if its against the rules, but I would be very pleased if someone could debug my code.
Im trying to get the data from form "meist" and but it into the database when submit is pressed.

PHP`

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("content") or die(mysql_error());

$meist = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meist']);

    $meist = $_POST['meist'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO content_data (meist) VALUES ($meist)" 
or die(mysql_error));

echo "Data Inserted!";
?>
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>Form Input Data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="input.php">
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="meist" name="meist" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
          name="submit" value="Sent"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.
 `

Comment: As an important aside, you should consider moving away from the mysql extension, as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Also, in your code you have the lines, `$meist = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['meist']);` followed by `$meist = $_POST['meist'];`. This means that not only are you using a deprecated extension, you actually are overwriting your input escaping! :O

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you are looking for something like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `content_data` (`meist`) VALUES ('$meist')") or die(mysql_error())
                                           missing quotes ^      ^  ^      missing ()'s ^^
                                                                    |
                                                            missing )
```

Comment: @JoosepSisas click the big checkmark, it's better than an upvote.

Comment: Quick out of topic question, what should I use instead of mySql than ? any suggestions ?

Comment: @JoosepSisas I'd recommend PDO. [PDO Tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)